# Can we get an explicit equation of motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, energy, momentum

I am looking at the following exercise:

> We have an electromagnetic field. The relation between energy and momentum of a particle with charge $q$ is 
>   \begin{equation}
> \left (\frac{E-q\phi}{c}\right )^2=m^2c^2+\left\Vert \mathbf{p}-\dfrac{\:q\:}{c}\mathbf{A}\right\Vert^2
> \tag{01}
> \end{equation}
>   where $c$ is the velocity of light and $\phi=\phi (\mathbf{x},t), \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x},t)$ are the scalar and vector potential of the field with values in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively. 
>   Find the relation between the velocity and momentum and the equation of motion.

I have done the following:

The relation between velocity and momentum is $\mathbf p=\gamma_v m \mathbf v$ 
where $\gamma_v$ is the Lorentz factor.

Substituting it in the given equation, and together with $\mathbf v(t) = \mathbf{\dot x}(t)$, we get the following: 
\begin{align}
\left (\frac{E-q\phi}{c}\right )^2 & = m^2c^2+\left\Vert \mathbf{p}-\dfrac{\:q\:}{c}\mathbf{A}\right\Vert^2=m^2c^2+\left\Vert \gamma_v m\mathbf{v}-\dfrac{\:q\:}{c}\mathbf{A}\right\Vert^2
\nonumber\\
&=m^2c^2+\left\Vert \gamma_v m\mathbf{\dot x}(t)-\dfrac{\:q\:}{c}\mathbf{A}\right\Vert^2
\tag{02}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\left\Vert \left(1-\dfrac{\Vert\mathbf{\dot x}(t)\Vert^2}{c^2}\right)^{\!\!\boldsymbol{-}\frac12 }\!\!m\, \mathbf{\dot x}(t)-\frac{q}{c}\mathbf{A}\left[\mathbf x(t), t\right]\right\Vert^2
=\left (\frac{E-q\phi\left[\mathbf x(t), t\right]}{c}\right )^2-m^2c^2
\tag{03}
\end{equation}

Do we just say that the equation motion $\mathbf{x}(t)$ satisfies the above equation? Or can we find the equation $\mathbf{x}(t)$ ?

Comment: Hint: Distinguish between kinetic and canonical momentum.

Comment: In addition to the point Qmechanic is making, also note that when people are talking about equations of motion, they usually mean the differential equation governing $\mathbf x(t)$. So the question probably doesn't want you to calculate   $\mathbf x(t)$ explicitly.

Comment: So, is what I have done correct? Or is the part of momentum wrong? @SahandTabatabaei

Comment: Is the general mometum in an electromagnetic field equal to $\bf p=\gamma_vm\bf v+q\bf A$ ? @Qmechanic